# How can I get Photoshop's "Save for Web" quality with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop

When I resize an image with photoshop's "Save for Web", it looks different than if I convert it with ImageMagick. Is there a setting I can change in ImageMagick to get same results as Photoshop? Here is an example.

The original:

[image]

"Save for Web" 30.01%
vs
`convert -geometry 30.01% home-button-full.png home-button-ipad.png`

[image] 
[image]

Enlarged so it's easier to see the difference:

Photoshop:

[image]

ImageMagick:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only immediate difference that's discoverable are these:

- Photoshop's result is `76x86` pixels in size.
- ImageMagick's result is `76x87` pixels in size.
- Photoshop's number of colors used by the PNG is `378`.
- ImageMagick's number of colors used by the PNG is `401`.
- Photoshop's filesize for the PNG is `4.239 Bytes`.
- ImageMagick's filesize for the PNG is `3.410 Bytes`.

I only know how to fix the first difference:

```
convert orig.png -scale 76x86\! scaled-76x86.png
```

(This command's result has reduced the number of uniq colors to `358`... but that's *by accident* only.)

As long as we don't know what other sort of filtering Photoshop's *Save for Web...* does apply, we have little chance to mimic its results exactly... You could try this:

```
convert orig.png -scale 76x86\! -interpolate bicubic scaled-76x86.png
```

Comment: Thanks! This produces *very* similar results to photoshop. In addition to the interpolate parameter, it seems important to use --scale instead of --geometry. With --geometry the interpolation doesn't have any effect...I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: @rob: To be honest -- my *eyes* couldn't discover much difference between your two initial results anyway... It was only thru some more 'scientific' analyzing methods that I found the differences and came up with the 'fix'.

Comment: It looks like photoshop does some sharpening when it resizes – it's very subtle – I'm just paranoid about loosing some of that sharpness by automating my resizing.

Comment: On ImageMagick 7.0.5-4 the command is `convert orig.png -scale 76x86\! -interpolate catrom scaled-76x86.png` as `bicubic` was deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see what re-sampling method (bicubic, bilinear, etc) you used in photoshop and make sure it's using the same method.

`-interpolate type` type being bicubic, bilinear, average, etc. [Interpolation type](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#interpolate)

According to the docs Imagemagick uses bilinear by default, whereas Photoshop uses Bicubic by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-quality` parameter if you want lossy compression instead. ImageMagick defaults to 100 (lossless) for jpgs.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality
http://www.simplesystems.org/RMagick/doc/imageattrs.html#quality